# How to ignore white spaces in awk command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, posix

I have a file user_list.txt which has a table of 4 fields separated by ",". For eg,

```
hi,hello,good morning,bye.
```

I'm using the below command to extract the third column field.

```
output=$(awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $3 }' user_list.txt)
```

When i try to check the contents of the output variable.,

```
echo ${output[0]} --> good
echo ${output[1]} --> morning
```

I want it as a string 
`echo ${output[0]} --> good morning`, but since whitespace is the default separator, the string is being split.

Please help.

Comment: Using bash and Gnu awk `echo $output` and `echo $output[0]` both produce `good morning`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Seems like this is a Bash question, not an Awk one, and you want `echo ${output}`.

Comment: if i use ( $( awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $3 }' user_list.txt) ) to store it to output, then i get., 
echo ${output[0]} --> good
echo ${output[1]} --> morning.

Comment: `output="$(awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $3 }' user_list.txt)"` with quotes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. although i'm facing one more issue. I need to print as follows., '"good morning". Am i doing it the proper way?

echo "$output" --> this yields me "$output". But i need "good morning"

Comment: There is something EXTREMELY broken about your shell if it's behaving as you say it is. I suspect though that theres just something else you're doing that you haven't told us about yet. Create a **minimal** script plus input file that reproduces your problem, save the script in a file named "mytest", execute the commands `cat -v user_list.txt; cat -v ./mytest; ./mytest | cat -v` and copy/paste the result into your question so we can see what you're really doing.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, the command to read **lines** of input into an array is [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile)

```bsh
mapfile -t output < <(awk -F, '{print $3}' user_list.txt) 

for element in "${output[@]}"    # <= the quotes are crucial here
do
    echo "have: $element"
done
```

If your input file is just a single line then use `cut`

```
output=$(cut -f, -d3 user_list.txt)
echo "have: $output"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the below command. Considering `user_list.txt` as input file.

```
awk '{split($0,a,","); print a[3]}' user_list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual, when you provide a small portion of a much bigger picture it is difficult to answer correctly.  It appears you want to do something in bash with values from the third column, so what is wrong with a simple loop:

```
while IFS=, read -r _ _ item _
do
  <do stuff with $item here>
done<user_list.txt
```

Of course I could be wrong as the question is poorly devised and makes it hard to render an actual answer